# How to query first 10 rows and next time query other 10 rows from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have more than 500 rows with in my Database Table with particular date.

To query the rows with particular date.

```
select * from msgtable where cdate='18/07/2012'
```

This returns 500 rows.

How to query these 500 rows by 10 rows step by step. 
Query First 10 Rows and show in browser,then query next 10 rows and show in browser?

Comment: mysql is not postgres and vice versa.

Comment: use pagination with ajax for batter result see this article  http://www.designaeon.com/jquery-ajax-pagination/

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just use the `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `msgtable` WHERE `cdate`='18/07/2012' LIMIT 10
```

And from the next call you can do this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `msgtable` WHERE `cdate`='18/07/2012' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

More information on `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` on [`LIMIT` and `OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/queries-limit.html).

Comment: Don't use backticks. You don't need them in this example to begin with, not even in MySQL. And you shouldn't use backticks to quote identifiers, *ever*. Use standard-compliant **double quotes** instead. Backticks are not ANSI-SQL compliant and don't work anywhere outside MySQL - where you don't have to use them either. Employ the [ANSI_QUOTES setting of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) to get rid of this for good.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I seriously don't understand. We need to use backticks for table names and user defined structure right?

Comment: You only *need* double quotes or backticks for identifiers if they contain special characters or reserved words. Use the mentioned ANSI_QUOTES setting and be done with backticks for good. More info in the [MySQL glossary of the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#id1661359).

Comment: Sure, thanks. Will take a look into it. :) But still am confused. Kinda got it now! :)

Comment: This needs an `order by`.

Comment: you can also you pagination to stack the rows in to 10 each.

Answer (score 13):

`LIMIT limit OFFSET offset` will work.

But you need a **stable `ORDER BY` clause**, or the values may be ordered differently for the next call (after any write on the table for instance).

```
SELECT *
FROM   msgtable
WHERE  cdate = '2012-07-18'
ORDER  BY msgtable_id  -- or whatever is stable 
LIMIT  10
OFFSET 50;  -- to skip to page 6
```

Use standard-conforming date style ([ISO 8601 in my example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)), which works irregardless of your locale settings.

Paging will still shift if involved rows are inserted or deleted or changed in relevant columns. It has to.

To avoid that shift or for better performance with big tables use **smarter paging strategies**:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

Comment: One cannot emphasize enough just how important having that ORDER BY clause is in order to conform to the standard *and* to ensure the query generates predictable output.

Comment: who keeps track of the offset ? db engine ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
SELECT sub.*, sub.rank as Rank
FROM
(
   SELECT *,  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rank
   FROM msgtable 
   WHERE cdate = '18/07/2012'
) sub
WHERE rank BETWEEN ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
  AND (@PageNum * @PageSize)
```

Every time you pass the parameters `@PageNum` and the `@PageSize` to get the specific page you want. For exmple the first 10 rows would be `@PageNum = 1 and @PageSize = 10`

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagination</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','northwind');
    $data_per_page = 10;
    $select = "SELECT * FROM `customers`";  
    $select_run = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $records = mysqli_num_rows($select_run);
    // while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($select_run)) {      
    //     echo $result['CompanyName'] . '<br>';        
    // }
    // $records;
    echo "<br>";
    $no_of_page = ceil($records / $data_per_page);
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = 1;
    }else{
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    $page_limit_data = ($page - 1) * 10;
    $select = "SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT " . $page_limit_data . ',' . $data_per_page ;
    $select_run = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    while ($row_select = mysqli_fetch_array($select_run)){
        echo $row_select['CompanyName'] . '<br>' ;
    }
    for($page=1; $page<= $no_of_page; $page++){ 
        echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=$page'> $page" . ', ';   
    }
?>
<br>
<h1> Testing Limit Functions Here  </h1>
<?php 
$limit = "SELECT CompanyName From customers LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5";
$limit_run = mysqli_query($conn , $limit);
while($limit_result = mysqli_fetch_array($limit_run)){
    echo $limit_result['CompanyName'] . '<br>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This page name is pagination.php

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

for first 10 rows...

```
SELECT * FROM msgtable WHERE cdate='18/07/2012' LIMIT 0,10
```

for next 10 rows

```
SELECT * FROM msgtable WHERE cdate='18/07/2012' LIMIT 10,10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [postgresql Cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR where * FROM msgtable where cdate='18/07/2012';
```

Then use

```
FETCH 10 FROM C;
```

to fetch 10 rows.

Finnish with

```
COMMIT;
```

to close the cursor.

But if you need to make a query in different processes, LIMIT and OFFSET as suggested by @Praveen Kumar is better

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I think you just need to implement Pagination.

```
$perPage = 10;

$pageNo = $_GET['page'];
```

Now find total rows in database.

```
$totalRows = Get By applying sql query;

$pages = ceil($totalRows/$perPage);    

$offset = ($pageNo - 1) * $perPage + 1

$sql = "SELECT * FROM msgtable WHERE cdate='18/07/2012' LIMIT ".$offset." ,".$perPage
```

Comment: This is insecure and could be used for sql injection purposes.  Please don't use this.